# Is there a way to refer to open-ended ranges in Google Sheets that are open in both ends?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that will grow in both dimensions, i.e. down and to the right. In a different summary table, I want to summarise the first table using `=index(match())` but I'm struggling with the open-endedness (that's a real term) of both the dimensions.

For a table that will grow down, I would use `=A1:A` and for a table that grows to the right I would use `=A1:1` but here I'm stuck with `=A1:` which throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

open to the right side:

```
=A1:1
```

open downwards:

```
=A1:Z
```

open in both linear directions:

```
=INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A); COLUMNS(1:1); 4))
```

or:

```
=INDIRECT("A1:"&ROWS(A:A))
```